# How to display all the categories a post is in

Tags: categories

How do I display all of the categories that a post is in, in sentence format.

eg. cars, boats, aircraft, bicycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop use `<?php the_category(', '); ?>` or outside the loop :

```
$post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );

foreach($post_categories as $c){
    $cat = get_category( $c );
    echo $cat->name . ",";
}
```

Comment: is there a spelling mistake there - you're using cats on one hand and cat on the other.  cats is not used anywhere else

Comment: @Steve deleted that , was planning a different way :)